# jQuery show current html element value

Tags: jquery

Here is the code:

html:

```
<div class="toggle">
    <a href="#" class="active">5</a>
    <a href="#" class="">10</a>
    <a href="#" class="">25</a>
    <a href="#" class="">50</a>
</div>

<span class="result"></span>
```

js:

```
$('.toggle a').click(function(){
    $('.toggle a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).closest('a').addClass('active');
    $('.result').html('???');

});
```

css:

```
.active {
    color: red;}
```

How can i show when I press 'a' it will show current 'a's number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(this).text()` will get you the contents of the tag that triggered the click.

```
$('.toggle a').click(function(){
    $('.toggle a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).closest('a').addClass('active');
    $('.result').html($(this).text());

});
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this will do the trick for you:

```
$('.toggle a').click(function(){
    $('.toggle a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).closest('a').addClass('active');
    $('.result').html($(this).text()); // The new line
});
```

What you need to do is to retrive the text in the "a" that was clicked. This can be done by calling the `text()` metod on `this` object.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.result').html( $(this).html() );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){

$('.toggle a').click(function(){
    var itemText=$(this).text();
    $('.toggle a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).closest('a').addClass('active');
    $('.result').html(itemText);

});        
})​
```

working sample http://jsfiddle.net/dvsrT/4/